# Flutter refresh button error with setState

Tags: flutter

I try to create a refresh button which reloads a layout and pulls date from a website (again). I tried using setState, but it does not work and only gives me an error.
The button should trigger the recreation of the *(tabbed)* layout

Here is my main:

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  {
  final GetWebsites _getWebsites = GetWebsites();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      refresh();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: getSites(),
    );
  }

  //Get sites => Document, store them in a Document list
  Widget getSites() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<html.Document>>(
      //gets Dates of each date in other class and puts it in an List -> snapshot
      future: _getWebsites.getWebsite(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot) {
        //Cases for Connections
        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return const Center(
              //TODO: Make better loading screen
              child: RefreshProgressIndicator(),
            );
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return const Center(
              child: Text("Keine Verbindung"),
            );
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('Fehler'),
              );
            }
            //create tabs
            return buildrefresh(snapshot);
        }
      },
    );
  }
  Widget buildrefresh(AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
        return refresh();
      },
      child: rowortabbedLayout(snapshot),
    );
  }

  Widget rowortabbedLayout(AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot) {
    if(Settings.getValue<bool>("keyrowortabbed", true)){
      return TabbedLayout().createTabbedLayout(snapshot, context);
    }else{
      return RowLayout().createRowLayout(snapshot, context);
    }
  }

  Future<void> refresh() async {
    setState((){
      FutureBuilder<List<html.Document>>(
        //gets Dates of each date in other class and puts it in an List -> snapshot
        future: _getWebsites.getWebsite(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot) {
          //Cases for Connections
          switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: RefreshProgressIndicator(),
              );
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return const Center(
                child: Text("Keine Verbindung"),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text('Fehler'),
                );
              }
              //create tabs
              return buildrefresh(snapshot);
          }
        },
      );
    });
    print("Do something!");
  }
  Future<void> setstaterefresh() async {
    setState((){});
    print("Do something!");
  }


}
```

And my second class where the Tabbed layout (and the button) is:

```
class TabbedLayout{
  final SiteParser _getSiteData = SiteParser();
  Widget createTabbedLayout(AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot, BuildContext context){
    return buildrevresh(snapshot,context);
  }

  Widget buildrevresh(AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot, BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
        return MyHomePageState().setstaterefresh();
      },
      child: tabcontroller(snapshot,context),
    );
  }

  Widget tabcontroller(AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot, BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(length: snapshot.data!.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            actions: <Widget> [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MySettings()),
                  );
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
              ),
 //Refresh Button:
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  MyHomePageState().refresh();
                },
              ),
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs:
              //Tab names
              tabBarMaker(snapshot),

            ),
            title: const Text("Vertretungsplan")
        ),
        body:
        TabBarView(
          children:
          tabMaker(snapshot),
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> tabBarMaker(AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot) {
    List<Tab> tabs = [];
    for(int x = 0; x<snapshot.data!.length; x++) {
      tabs.add(Tab(text: snapshot.data![x].querySelector('h1.list-table-caption')!.text
          .toString()));
    }
    return tabs;
  }

  //Create Tabs with contetnt for each site
  List<Widget> tabMaker(AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot) {
    List<Widget> tabwidgets = [];
    for(int x = 0; x<snapshot.data!.length; x++) {
      tabwidgets.add(_buildDay(snapshot.data![x]));
    }
    return tabwidgets;
  }

  //Widget to create Tabs of each day and their contents

  //Get Contents of a day
  Widget _buildDay(html.Document site) {
    List<tage> days = _getSiteData.getData(site);
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      itemCount: days.length,
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        //Build cards for each content
        return MyThemes().buildCard(days[index]);
      },
    );
  }

}
```

And here is the error log:

```
E/flutter (13792): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor: MyHomePageState#a8b0c(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
E/flutter (13792): This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.
E/flutter (13792): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1076:9)
E/flutter (13792): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1087:6)
E/flutter (13792): #2      MyHomePageState.refresh (package:khsplan/main.dart:140:5)
E/flutter (13792): #3      TabbedLayout.tabcontroller.<anonymous closure> (package:khsplan/Vplan/tabbedlayout.dart:42:37)
E/flutter (13792): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
E/flutter (13792): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
E/flutter (13792): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
E/flutter (13792): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter (13792): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
E/flutter (13792): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:558:9)
E/flutter (13792): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
E/flutter (13792): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
E/flutter (13792): #12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
E/flutter (13792): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
E/flutter (13792): #14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
E/flutter (13792): #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:19)
E/flutter (13792): #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
E/flutter (13792): #17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
E/flutter (13792): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter (13792): #19     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter (13792): #20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter (13792): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter (13792): #22     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
E/flutter (13792): #23     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (13792): #24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (13792): #25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:185:10)
E/flutter (13792): #26     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
E/flutter (13792): #27     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:98:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error could be on the Switch case option `ConnectionState.active` it's not stopping or something, it continues to `ConnectionState.waiting`, so I would try adding something like a `break` statemente meanwhile you add another feature there:

```dart
Future<void> refresh() async {
    setState((){
      FutureBuilder<List<html.Document>>(
        //gets Dates of each date in other class and puts it in an List -> snapshot
        future: _getWebsites.getWebsite(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<html.Document>> snapshot) {
          //Cases for Connections
          switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
            // ! ADDING CODE HERE
            case ConnectionState.active:
              // ! ADDING CODE HERE
              break;
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: RefreshProgressIndicator(),
              );
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return const Center(
                child: Text("Keine Verbindung"),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text('Fehler'),
                );
              }
              //create tabs
              return buildrefresh(snapshot);
          }
        },
      );
    });
    print("Do something!");
  }
```

I hope that was helpful .

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but, this was not cause of the error. I could resolve this by creating the overlay in the main class and later generate stuff i need. This gives me an error tho but it does work